# Pandas: Add two rows if column value is the same (add integers as strings)

Tags: pandas

I have following pd.DataFrame (for explination the excel output):
[image: Excel Output]

So what i need: If the Value of 'Zeitsumme' is identical (ex. Row 14 & 15) i need to merge this two rows (works already). Now the complicated part: Column 'V/MV' and 't/s' should add up as Text (example: "1.1 & 0.1" and "0 & 1), Column 'Zeitsumme' should have the Value (ex. 1) and Column 'Wert' should be the sum (ex. 52) - so this new row should replace the old two.

My Code:

[image: Code]

XX and XY are placeholders, bc. i couldnt find something for my needs.

Ty!

Comment: Post img as text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lambda function with converting to strings and `join`:

```
f = lambda x: ' & '.join(x.astype(str))
aggregate_functions = {'V / MV':f, 't / s':f, 'Wert':'sum'}

df = df.groupby('Zeitsumme').agg(aggregate_functions)
```